# Many to many relation in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have 2 models model A and model B as  below

```
class ModelA(TimeStampedModel):
    field_a= models.TextField(default="")
    field_b= models.ManyToManyField("ModelB",
                    related_name="modeA_modelB", blank=True)

class ModelB(TimeStampedModel):
    field_c= models.TextField(default="")
    field_d= models.ManyToManyField("ModelA",
                    related_name="modeB_modelA", blank=True)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever a model A is assigned to model B instance it should reflect in model B as well.

For example: A particular terms and conditions have several policy that will be model A, next in  model B, I need to have field _d having the list of terms and condition which have that policy.

Answer (score 0):

This is already the case, the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so in this case a way to obtain the `ModelA` objects linked to a `ModelB` object. We thus can work with a *single* `ManyToManyField`:

```
class ModelA(TimeStampedModel):
    field_a= models.TextField(default='')
    field_b= models.ManyToManyField(
        'ModelB',
        related_name='field_d',
        blank=True
    )

class ModelB(TimeStampedModel):
    field_c = models.TextField(default='')
    # no field_d
```

If you now for example make a `ModelA` and a `ModelB` object, and you add the `ModelB` object to `field_b`, then in `field_d` of that `ModelB` object, it will contain the corresponding `ModelA` object:

```
my_a = ModelA.objects.create(field_a='foo')
my_b = ModelB.objects.create(field_c='foo')
my_a.field_b.add(my_b)
my_a.field_d.all()  # a queryset that contains my_b
```

Comment: what about the scenerio where  i need a queryset that contains my_a from modelB?

Comment: If you have a `ModelB` *object* `my_b`, you can use `my_b.field_b.all()`